# Very bad performance using 3 tables join on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, data-warehouse

I have serious performance issue when I execute a SQL statements which involves 3 tables as following:

TableA<----TableB---->TableC

In particular, these tables are in a data warehouse and the table in the middle is a dimension table while the others are fact tables. TableA has about 9 millions of record, while TableC about 3 million. The dimension table (TableB) only 74 records.

The syntax of the query is very simple, as you can see, where TableA is called _PG, TableB is equal to _MDT and Table C is called _FM:

```
SELECT _MDT.codiceMandato as Customer, SUM(_FM.Totale) AS Revenue,
      SUM(_PG.ErogatoTotale) AS Paid
FROM _PG INNER JOIN
     _MDT 
     ON _PG.idMandato = _MDT.idMandato INNER JOIN
     _FM
     ON _FM.idMandato = _MDT.idMandato
GROUP BY _MDT.codiceMandato
```

Actually, I never has seen the end of this query :-(
_PG has a non clustered index on idMandato and the same _FM table
_MDT table has a clustered index on idMandato

and the execution plan is the following

[image: Execution Plan]

As you can see the bottleneck is due to Stream Aggregate (33% of cost) and Merge Join (66% of cost). In particular, the stream aggregate underlines about 400 billions of estimated rows!!
I don’t know the reasons and I don’t know how to proceed in order to solve this bad issue.
I use SQL Server 2016 SP1 installed of a virtual server with Windows Server 2012 Standard with 4 Cpu core and 32 GB of RAM , 1,5TB on a dedicated volume made up SAS disks with SSD cache.
I hope anybody can help me to understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what your tables really look like.

Comment: Try adding the `Totale` and `ErogatoTotale` as included columns of the non-clustered indexes.

Comment: The estimated might be correct :-) In both fact tables `idMandato` is probably very non-unique and you actually do a M:N-join. Depending on your actual question you might sum each fact table before the join using CTEs/Derived Tables.

Comment: The relationship between table 1:N----1:1-----1:N following a star schema model.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is because you are getting a Cartesian product along two dimensions.  This multiplies the rows unnecessarily.  The solution is to aggregate before doing the `join`.

You haven't provided sample data, but this is the idea:

```
SELECT m.codiceMandato as Customer, f.revenue, p.Paid
FROM _MDT m INNER JOIN
     (SELECT p.idMandato, SUM(p.ErogatoTotale) AS Paid
      FROM _PG p
      GROUP BY p.idMandato
     ) p
     ON p.idMandato = m.idMandato INNER JOIN
     (SELECT f.idMandato, SUM(f.Totale) AS Revenue
      FROM _FM f
      GROUP BY f.idMandato
     ) f
     ON f.idMandato = m.idMandato;
```

I'm not 100% sure this will fix the problem, because your data structure is not clear.

Comment: No final GROUP BY needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a subquery between TableA and TableC without aggregation and then joining this subquery with TableB and apply the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT _MDT.codiceMandato, SUM(A.Totale) AS Revenue, sum( A.ErogatoTotale) 
AS Paid
FROM ( SELECT m.idMandato, _FM.Totale, _PG.ErogatoTotale  FROM _PG 
INNER JOIN _FM  
    ON _FM.idMandato = _MDT.idMandato ) A
    INNER JOIN _MDT       ON A.idMandato = _MDT.idMandato 
GROUP BY _MDT.codiceMandato
```